# Efficient frequency domain search for reduced number of hypotheses

Tags: software-defined-radio, cdma, gnss

In CDMA signals (such as GNSS) there are two unknown parameters when one receives the signal, residual carrier frequency and an unknown delay. Assuming the carrier frequency residual is known, what is left to find is the delay between the input signal and the gold code modulated into the signal. With no prior information all hypotheses have to be search (i.e the input signal has to be cross-correlated with a gold code replica shifted by the code delay hypothesis $N$ times).

This can be done in a very efficient way in the frequency domain when all hypothesis must be search, e.g we have an input signal and a code $N$ samples long and we must search $N$ delay hypothesis to find the one that gives the highest cross-correlation magnitude.

Now, let's say I want to search only every $M$ hypotheses evenly spaced, where $N/M$ is an integer, so delay $0,M,2M,3M,\ldots, N$.

Is there still a way to solve this problem in the frequency domain efficiently without losing information?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can reduce only a little bit the number of operations.

For example, an N-point FFT can be computed using two N/2-point FFTs as follows
[image: FFT splitting]

Therefore, a correlation traditionally computed as
[image]

can be computed as
[image]

If you are interested only in the even samples of the correlation, you can discard one FFT and save some operations:
[image]

There exist different ways to split an FFT or a correlation. The following one is more efficient because it does not require the multiplication with complex exponential.
[image]

Source of the pictures above: http://dx.doi.org/10.5075/epfl-thesis-6190, Chapter 4.

You can do something similar if you want to keep only one sample over 3, or one sample over 4, ..., but the technique shown above becomes less and less efficient (but it can be useful if you have a lot of zero-padding, see e.g. https://doi.org/10.1155/2015/765898 that applies it to GNSS signals with a splitting by 3).